# Action<T> or Action<in T>?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, delegates

I was reading about Action Delegate on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) and so this under syntax

```
 public delegate void Action<in T>(T obj);
```

Than I looked in [c-sharpcorner.com](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/anonymousMethods04022006141542PM/anonymousMethods.aspx) and it used this syntax

```
public delegate void Action<T>(T obj);
```

As you can see there is no `in` before T.
Which syntax is right and what does that `in` mean?
EDIT: The same syntax used for `Predicate`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `in` part is for [covariance and contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29) and was introduced in .NET 4.0, the article you link to was published in 2006 before .NET 4.0 was released (so obviously it doesn't refer co[ntra]variance).

Answer (score 11):

`in` and `out` (generic contravariance and covariance) were only introduced in C# 4, and the delegates and interfaces were modified for .NET 4 - so `Action<T>` in .NET 3.5 became `Action<in T>` in .NET 4.

The article you're referring to is from 2006, well before .NET 4 came out.

If you change which version of MSDN you're displaying, you'll see the change - for example, the [.NET 3.5 version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=VS.90).aspx) shows it without the `in`.

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth noting that conceptually all delegate types could in theory be inherently covariant with any type parameter used only as the return type and contravariant with regard to type parameters used only for method parameters passed by value, and compilers could automatically allow for such variance, except for one problem: while the `in` declaration of `Action` will prevent the compiler from squawking if an `Action<Animal>` is passed to a method that expects an `Action<Cat>`, some methods that expect an `Action<Cat>` may behave very badly if given an `Action<Animal>`.  In general, methods which should only accept delegates of types with covariance/contravariance specifiers if they will work correctly with all such delegates; otherwise they should accept delegate types without such specifiers.

*Most* methods which accept an `Action<Cat>` will work just fine with an `Action<Animal>`, so Microsoft decided retroactively to make `Action<T>` contravariant.  Because many methods which accept an `EventHandler<T>` could fail very badly if given anything that didn't perfectly match the expected type, `EventHandler<T>` was not made contravariant.

In retrospect, if each delegate type had defined its own `Combine` method, it would have been possible to make delegate covariance and contravariance work in almost all cases.  If `CatEventArgs:AnimalEventArgs`, saying

```
EventHandler<CatEventArgs> myEvents=null;
void AddEvent(EventHandler<CatEventArgs> newEvent)
{
  myEvents = EventHandler<CatEventArgs>.Combine(myEvents, newEvent);
}
```

could have turned a passed-in `EventHandler<AnimalEventsArgs>` into an `EventHandler<CatEventArgs>`, which could then be combined with any other delegate that could likewise be converted into an `EventHandler<CatEventArgs>`.  Unfortunately, since `Combine` was only defined on `Delegate`, there's no way by which the `Combine` method can know what delegate type is needed by the calling code [IMHO, even without covariance/contravariance, it would have been nice to have delegates define their own `Combine` and `Remove` methods, since that would have avoided the need to typecast the result of `Delegate.Combine`].